# Zero-padding a number to have six digits

Tags: javascript, formatting

This is a switch statement in JavaScript. I have a feeling that it can be done in a shorter way.

```
switch(n.length){
  case 1:
    n = '00000' + n;
  break;
  case 2:
    n = '0000' + n;
  break;
  case 3:
    n = '000' + n;
  break;
  case 4:
    n = '00' + n;
  break;
  case 5:
    n = '0' + n;
  break;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what this is being used for. It's pretty non-general.

Comment: @HackSaw I believe it's used for left-padding a number. There's a better padding function out there as well: [click me](http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/31/javascript-string-trimming-and-padding/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function foobar(n)
{
    var zeroes = "000000";
    return zeroes.substr(n.length) + n.toString();
}
```

Comment: ps: there's a small error in the code, it should be: `zeroes.substr(n.length) + n.toString();`

Comment: Then why you don't use n.length in your code?

Comment: lol sorry, the same mistake is in my code :) anyway thank you, I just needed the idea

Comment: You don’t need the variable. The name `zeroes` doesn’t add any meaning, so `"000000".substr(n.length)` is just as clear, and more succinct.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the value of `n` is known in each case, so you can just put it in the string:

```
switch(n) {
  case 1:
    n = '000001';
  break;
  case 2:
    n = '00002';
  break;
  case 3:
    n = '0003';
  break;
  case 4:
    n = '004';
  break;
  case 5:
    n = '05';
  break;
}
```

If `n` can only have one of these values, you can use it as index in an array:

```
n = ['000001','00002','0003','004','05'][n - 1];
```

#### Edit:

With the edited code (using `n.length` in the switch), it would be:

```
n = ['00000','0000','000','00','0'][n.length - 1] + n;
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems you're trying to implement part of the functionality of printf.
Use one of the existing implementations, e.g. [dive.into.javascripts sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)
to do the zero-padding:

```
n = sprintf("%06d", n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently the other answers do not provide a robust way of doing this.  They either use magic numbers or create long strings of zeroes manually.  So I am adding this answer as a reference for anyone visiting this question in the future.

We can create the padding by joining an empty array together.  I have provided two options: straight code or a function for reuse.

Straight Code:

```
var desiredLength = 6;

if (n.length < desiredLength) {
   n = Array(desiredLength - n.length + 1).join("0") + n;
}
```

Function:

```
function padTo(length, str, ch) {
   if (str.length < length) {
      return Array(length - str.length + 1).join(ch) + str;
   }

   return str;
} 

// Usage
padTo(6, "3", "0")); // 000003
```